# How to clone mongodb database from data folder?

Tags: mongodb

I have a server with MongoDB 4 500GB database.
I have a very short backup window to create a copy of the database on the same server, mongodump/mongorestore work pretty slow. 
I can copy mongo data folder, but I don't know what should I do next to create a clone of the existing database.
Can I somehow create a copy of the existing database by files manipulation or with some wild tiger utility?

Comment: Take a snapshot of the underlying storage, and backup from the snapshot.

Comment: Ok. I have database1 in /data folder and database1 in /data.bak folder. Folders are the same. How to create database2 in /data folder which is clone of database1?